# checkbox-customization

Tags: html, firefox, css

I have used following code for getting rounded corners on a checkbox

```css
input[type=checkbox]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #cacece;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}
```

But its not working in Mozilla. Can you sugest me some code please?

Comment: There's an error in your code, you should have a semi-colon before `display: inline-block` (note this doesn't solve the question)

Comment: You could try the jQuery UI for this. So easy to use :) http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

Comment: Or, if you are using jQuery there's a nice plugin http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1):

This post is old but this is what i suggest:

Associate labels to your checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="c1" />
<label class="check" for="c1"></label>
```

Hide by css your checkboxes:

```
.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]{
    display:none
}
```

Style the label as you want to. I created a simple jsfiddle that fully demonstrate how to use personnalise checkboxes. I keep them square in my example but you could add your border radius easily in the css.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KTADZ/1/) is the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes (radio buttons and SELECT) are rather OS-specific, and are generated by the OS more than the browser. The ability to style these elements has always been quite limited.